# Basics of configuration initialization strategies used in molecular dynamics?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, mathematical-modeling

[This answer to *Basics of numerical energy minimization techniques used in molecular dynamics?*](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/8762/201) mentions

> conjugate gradients, BFGS for energy minimization

and

> Metropolis Monte Carlo (and the) the FIRE algorithm

for dynamical simulations.

While the metropolis method has the potential to discover many adjacent minima depending on how high of a temperature it starts with and how rapidly it cools ([annealing schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing#The_annealing_schedule)) the others will tend to find minima near where they are initialized and not necessarily find the global minimum.

**Question:** What are the basics of configuration initialization strategies used in molecular dynamics simulations? Is this an art based on intuition and a "feel" for the problem? Does one first start with a project budget (e.g. "I've got three months to get results and \$10,000 to spend on supercomputer time") and sprinkle it randomly over initial configuration space?

Of course different types of problems may require very different strategies and all answers are welcome. But for what I'm doing the questions below describes my plan to make a basic molecular dynamics calculation using a Python script rather than a canned, self-contained program.

- [How amenable is this 2D Frenkel–Kontorova-like energy minimization problem in Python to the use of a modest PC + GPU? (Heavy reliance on indexing)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40634/17869)  (SciComp SE)
- [Going to try to move some of my scipy/numpy calculation to a new GPU, how to avoid disappointing results?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/40614/17869)  (SciComp SE)
- [DIY molecular dynamics for Xenes on crystal surfaces; where can I get applicable open-source force field parameters that I can use in my scripts?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8755/201)

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate so I've voted to close, but maybe it isn't and there's a great answer to this question out there that's not an answer to the proposed duplicate?

Comment: Please don't do annealing with Metropolis Monte Carlo to find the minimum, it isn't the 90's anymore. I think fad is thankfully fading. Same with in MD. Start at your temperature of interest, and end there.

Comment: in general, you either randomly insert particles, or place them on a lattice. See Frenkel & Smit, or Allen & Tildesly. Or, you use software to "pack" them in, like Packmol

Comment: Then you just start making moves or stepping through time, that simple (if MD, minimize energy so that there is no particles overlapping, this will cause an explosion)

Comment: @B.Kelly "it isn't the 90's anymore" Ha! Everything I know today I learned in the 90's or in Stack Exchange, and luckily the latter is increasing almost as fast as the former is fading

Comment: Gromacs has a nice "insert-molecules" algorithm that inserts your molecule in, checks if any van der waal radii are overlapping and if not leaves it. if overlapping, tries at a different center-of-mass location. I believe it puts a random rotation on it when picking a spot as well. Placing on a lattice is the simplest. You can make your box quite big, so that molecules don't overlap when placed in lattice position, then use NPT to shrink the box, or if it is a small change, you can even just scale it then energy minimize, or monte carlo

Comment: @B.Kelly thanks for Frenkel & Smit and words of encouragement; so I'm off to the library today. At first I'll start with an  [ordered honeycomb lattice](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40634/17869) on a crystal surface with a bit of scatter only; I'm interested in how the 2D island might translate or rotate to find a different and/or lower energy situation. Later I'll introduce defects (missing or extra atoms) but at that point I may be in over my head and have to use existing and well characterized software instead of my DIY efforts.

Comment: For crystals, Frenkel & smit may not be of as much help. The lattice routine I mention is more for prepping a liquid. I would be the wrong person to ask for solids, but I would check out http://leandro.iqm.unicamp.br/m3g/packmol/home.shtml. even packmol may not help all that much for a crystal.

Comment: @B.Kelly PACKMOL would make for an excellent general answer here. For my application we can think of it as a simulation of mostly internal degrees of freedom of a single big molecule, sitting on a surface which I'll simulate as a fixed potential field. The atoms and bonds are already identified and indexed, but it's the exact atom locations and therefore bond lengths and angles that needs to be populated.

Comment: @B.Kelly I have Frenkel & Smit now and I think it's an excellent recommendation because it seems to start at the beginning and go slowly and carefully through things methodically in an easy to understand way. Yes it's geared more to molecules in solutions than adsorbed layers on crystal surfaces but a lot of the physics and intuition still applies. Thanks once again!

Comment: Interesting discussion here!

Comment: @uhoh I am glad you find it useful, also check out https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/examples, which accompanies their textbook. Also, there is a python folder there, in it is all the same exercises as for Fortran, just written in python. It is a real gem.